# nginx, access to other servers on internal network

Tags: docker, nginx

I have a docker network running with this configuration (from docker-compose.yaml):

```
    networks:
      network:
        driver: bridge
        ipam:
          driver: default
          config:
            - subnet: 172.28.1.0/24
```

(My network is named network)

I have an Angular frontend running in a container on this network (172.28.1.4). The frontend web server is an nginx server.

From the web server I would like calls to various backends (authentication and database) to go directly to these servers without exposing them to the outside world.

I.e to authenticate a user, something like this: httpClient.post('172.28.1.5:8080/_user/login', credentials)

I believe this should be done in the nginx configuration, but I am pretty clueless on how to allow access to 172.28.1.5 from nginx without exposing 172.28.1.5

The servers are visible to each other seen from a Docker perspective

I have tried using a reverse proxy and that works, but I cannot block access to the location from external ips

```
    location ~/_user(/.*)*/?$ {
        proxy_pass         http://auth_server:8080; //auth_server points to 172.28.1.5
        proxy_redirect     off;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    }
```

The proxy setup. I have changed the names of the servers to clarify their role in the network.
The frontend can call the database_server like this:

http://external.ip.address:443/_api/any_path
Unfortunately, so can anyone else :)

```
        server {
            listen 443;
            server_name localhost;

            location ~/_user(/.*)*/?$ {
                proxy_pass         http://authentication_server:8080;
                proxy_redirect     off;
                proxy_set_header   Host $host;
                proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
            }

            location ~/_api(/.*)*/?$ {
                proxy_pass         http://database_server:80;
                proxy_redirect     off;
                proxy_set_header   Host $host;
                proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
            }

            location ~/ {
                proxy_pass         http://ui_frontend_server:8080;
                proxy_redirect     off;
                proxy_set_header   Host $host;
                proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
            }

        }
```

My docker setup makes this possible as it maps the name "authentication_server" with 172.28.1.3

```
        authentication_server_service:
            container_name: authentication_server
            build: ../authentication_server/
            image: authentication_server_image:latest
            networks:
            network:
                ipv4_address: 172.28.1.3
```

Comment: Are database and authentication containers as well?

Comment: Yes, the database server is on 172.28.1.x and it is a container

Comment: Show me your complete compose file. Access through reverse proxy should be the way to go, as long as you're not exposing any ports to the outside world, they should not be accessible through external ips.

Comment: [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation describes the standard network setup; you don't need `expose:` or `ports:` to make connections between containers.  In most cases you can't reach container-internal IPs directly and you should almost never manually set them.

Comment: I have added the proxy server setup part.